# I want to place a box containing potential images and text below each the main images

Tags: html, css, layout

[image]Whenever I try, it keeps placing the "img1" box beside the image instead of below the image.

How can I fix it so `img1` is placed below the image and has the same width as the images and its height would make up for the remainder of the page (height of page - height of image = height of this new box)?

My code:

```html
    </section>
    <section class = "product"> 
      <div class="product-list">
        <div class="product-item newnsx-item">
          <div class="product-text">
            <h2>23' NSX Type S</h2>
            <p class="p2">
              The Finale
            </p>
          </div>
          <img src="images/acuransx.avif" alt="Description of Image" class="newnsx" />
          <div class="img1">One</div>
     
       
        </div>
```

CSS

```css
.product-list {
    display:block;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-top: 50px;

    align-items: center;
    
  }

  .product-list .product-text {
    flex: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;  /* Adjust this value to move the text down as needed */
}

  .product-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 50px;

    position: relative;

  }

  .img1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    width: calc(60% - 20px); /* To match the width of the images above */
    margin-left: 25px; /* To match the left padding of the images */
    margin-right: 25px; /* To match the right padding of the images */
    height: calc(100vh - 100%); /* This needs to be dynamically calculated if the image height is not fixed */
    background-color: blue; /* The blue background */
    border-radius: 10px; /* The rounded edges */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* To include padding and border in the width and height */
  }
  

  .newnsx-item .product-text {
    order: 1;
  }

  
  
  .nsxtyper-item {
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    
  }


  
  .newnsx, .nsxtyper, .oldnsx, .firstnsx {
    width: calc(60% - 20px); /* Subtract some space for margin */
    max-width: 1000px; /* Adjust based on your preference */
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-right: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .product-list .product-text {
    flex: 5px;
  }
  
  .product-list h2{
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333333;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
 

  }

  .product-list h3{
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333333;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    
  
  }
  
  .product-list p.p2{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .product-list p.p3{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

As you can see right now, its just overlapping the next image instead of pushing it down

Im trying to have to appear below each image i have with the same padding as the image while not ruining the existing formatting. Im new to css and html so if theres a way to re-write this code which would make life alot easier as well please let me know.

Comment: Just check your HTML code because there is a closing `</section>` tag at the top and the section tag coming after that is not closed. Some of the divs aren't closed either

Comment: oh that snippet is incomplete, i believe their closed off properly